# Shared memory Vs QPI

Tags: mpi, shared-memory

Assume there is a node of two processors having 8 cores each (Intel Sandy Bridge E5-2670). Each processor is fitted in a separate socket. Hence there are 8 cores in each socket. Suppose I have two processes - one on socket 1 and one on socket 2 and they communicate. How can I find if they use QPI (Quick Path Interconnect) for communication OR some form of shared memory ?
(Each socket has a shared L3 cache - 20 MB and shared RAM of 16GB).

Comment: QPI is user between sockets. That's how you know. And QPI implements shared memory, so you have a false dichotomy here.

Comment: @Jeff: It will be great if you can explain it a bit further as to how QPI uses shared memory. Thanks !

Comment: QPI is the implementation of shared memory for multi-socket systems on Intel processors. Read Wikipedia entry for details.